# moving and walking around a scene using First Person Controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to replace the `Main Camera` with a `First Person Controller` by selecting `Assets`, then `Import Package`, and then `Character Controller`.

The package imports and I have a number of scripts and prefabs, but what is actually the first step in using it? In other words, how do I enable walking around my plane once I have all the imports?

Thanks

Comment: This question is definitely not suitable for SO. Watch some youtube tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to character controller in assets you imported, drag and drop the first person controller on the surface of plane in scene window.

Make sure it's on plane else Unity3d have by default gravity which will keep on dragging down your First person model to void.

You can check different tutorials about TPC(Third Person Controller) and FPS(First Person Controller) in Unity3D.